# How to distinguish the specific device from the multiple serial COM ports?

Tags: python, pyserial

I'm writing a python program. One of the function of the program is to gets the current latitude and longitude from a GPS receiver via USB. However, the computer must connect OBD-II(On-Board Diagnostics) via USB to get data from a vehicle. I can find all available serial COM ports in the computer, but I cannot distinguish the GPS receiver from serial COM ports, because the two devices represent the similar label in the computer.

The label:

```
Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM5)
Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM6)
```

My test code:

```py
import serial
import pynmea2
import time
import traceback
import serial.tools.list_ports

def get_NMEA2_GPS():
    try:
        portList = list(serial.tools.list_ports_windows.comports())
        ser = None
        for port in portList:
            # print("-"*10)
            # print(port.usb_info())
            # print("Port: [%s], device: [%s], description: [%s]" %(str(port), str(port.device), str(port.description)))
            if "Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port" in port.description:
                ser = serial.Serial(port[0], "4800", timeout = 1.0)
                print("Start to obtain GPS via NMEA")
                break
            # End of if-condition
        # End of for-loop
        
        
        while True:
            # print("GPS data:" + data )
            data = ser.readline().decode('ascii').strip()
            print(data)
            try:  
                msg = pynmea2.parse(data)
                
            except pynmea2.nmea.ParseError:
                print("Warning: The checksum of the sentence is wrong!")
                continue
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                continue
            else: 
                if msg.sentence_type == "RMC":
                    latitude = msg.latitude
                    longitude = msg.longitude
                    print("----The current position: %2.8f, %3.8f" %(latitude, longitude))
            # time.sleep(0.1)  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stop obtain GPS information!")
        ser.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Error: 無法與GPS sensor連線")
        traceback.print_exc()

def main():
    get_NMEA2_GPS()
    print("="*60)
    print("Finish!")
    input("Please enter any key!")
# End of main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# End of if-condition
```

I'm sure that COM5 is the GPS receiver, and COM6 is OBD-II. However, the COM port of the GPS receiver may change because I cannot expect that user plugs the GPS receiver into the same USB port. By the way, the OS that I use is Windows 10 64-bit. Could anyone give me any suggestion, please?

Comment: Does the GPS device blather by itself?  Or does it need to be queried?

Comment: Can you share the 'port.description' here, or is it empty ?

Comment: I get the 'port.description':                                                                               
 `Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM5)` and
`Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM6)
`

Answer (score 0):

Com ports have a "description" part which you are searching for, doesn't seem to be anything identifiable via the description between the two devices. I would look at hardware id, I would guess those would be unique? port.hwid  That is where I would start. Maybe print all the information each port gives you and look for other identifiable information.

I don't know specifically about the hardware of the two devices you are looking at. I just know I've used hwid in the past (or with some usb, vid/pid or serial number)

(https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html)